# Saving Loop Variables in Different CSV Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

For a current project, I am planning to save the variables generated in a number of loops in different CSV files.

For the script below, I am however not receiving any usuable output, most likely due to the wrong order of commands (have modified things and received all kinds of results such as 44 empty files, only file 43 with full content  etc).

Is there any smart tweak to have the output saved in CSV on a loop by loop basis? The corresponding part of the code looks like this:

```
# Allocate periods for individual CSV file names
    periods = pd.period_range('2009Q1','2018Q4',freq='Q')
    ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(40), periods)
    type(ts.index)
    intervals = ts.index

    # Create individual file names
    for i in intervals:
        name = 'Glassdoor_A_' + str(i)

        # Print the contents of dictionary
        for key in list(d.keys()):
            print(key, ":", d[key])

            # Count the total number of words
            total = sum(d.values())
            percent = d[key] / total

            print(d[key], total, percent)

        # Save output in CSV file
        with open(name+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(["Word", "Occurrences", "Percentage"])
            writer.writerows([[key, val, val / total] for key, val in d.items()])
```

Comment: You did not ever use your output, what is it for?

Comment: It's a word anlysis, counting the number of unique words within a JSON file

Comment: Have you tried pd.to_csv()?

Comment: The writing seems to work - the challenge is rather to write the results into 44 different CSV files...

Comment: Maybe I missed sth, but I did not see how you use the variable 'output'  when you write the file; in addition, where does another variable d come from? Keeping trace of your variables is essential here.

Comment: Ok got your point now. The results shall relate to `# Loading and reading dataset: file = open("Glassdoor_A.json", "r"), data = json.load(file), df = pd.json_normalize(data), df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` `# Create an empty dictionary, d = dict()`. Referring the iteration to `d` would be the right approach I guess...

Comment: A few things.. This `writer.writerows([key, d[key], d[key] / total] for key in list(d.keys()))` does not look like valid syntax. Comprehensions should be enclosed like so. `writer.writerows([[key, d[key], d[key] / total] for key in list(d.keys())])`. Additionally, it could be written much more succinctly like so. `writer.writerows([[key, val, val / total] for key, val in d.items()])`.

Comment: Good point, thanks for highlighting this - I have amended things accordingly (also in the original question code shown). The main challenge is still around the different CSV files, while I am currently receiving 44 files with exactly the same content.